# Distances between embedded word vector

Tags: python, nlp, word2vec, move-semantics

I would need to find a relationship between the word `4G` , 5G and `mobile phones` or `Internet` in order to cluster sentences about technology all together.
Following a suggestion, I used for this purpose word2vec.

I have tried as follows:

```
from time import time
start_nb = time()

# Initialize logging.
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s')

sentence_1 = '4G is the fourth generation of broadband network.'
sentence_2 = 'I bought a new mobile phone. '
sentence_1 = sentence_1.lower().split()
sentence_2 = sentence_2.lower().split()

# Import and download stopwords from NLTK.
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk import download
download('stopwords')  # Download stopwords list.

# Remove stopwords.
stop_words = stopwords.words('english')
sentence_1 = [w for w in sentence_1 if w not in stop_words]
sentence_2 = [w for w in sentence_2 if w not in stop_words]


start = time()
import os

from gensim.models import Word2Vec
if not os.path.exists('/data/w2v_googlenews/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz'):
    raise ValueError("SKIP: You need to download the google news model")
    
model = Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format('/data/w2v_googlenews/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz', binary=True)


distance = model.wmdistance(sentence_1, sentence_2)
print 'distance = %.4f' % distance

sentence_3 = '5G is dangerous!'
sentence_3 = sentence_3.lower().split()
sentence_3 = [w for w in sentence_3 if w not in stop_words]

distance = model.wmdistance(sentence_1, sentence_3)
distance = model.wmdistance(sentence_2, sentence_3)
```

The results do not show a relevant connection between 4G, 5G and mobile phone.  I would like to show their relevant connection visually, for example like in this plot

[image]

but with 4G, 5G and mobile phones.

However the main problem (this is my question) is how to improve the connection/distance between these words.

Comment: Without seeing your output values, it's unclear what makes you unhappy about the results, or what you might consider better. Which of the two sentences do you **want** to be less-distant from your third? Also, some of your words might not be in the (2013 news-article-based) `GoogleNews` vectors. (Is `'5g'` there? Your token '`dangerous!'`  with exclamation point – is unlikely there.)

Comment: Have you verified which of the tokens `'5G'`, `'mobile'`, `'phones'`, or `'mobile phones'` are in your set of word-vectors? It would be better to see the exact values, as printed, alongside your code in your question, but whatever the values are – what makes you think those values are insufficient? (As all your test sentences are about mobile phones in different aspects, it's not clear any should be much further from the others.)

Comment: I mean, the actual values your code printed. Without showing your code, it's hard to know what you mean by "tried to use iPhone and smartphone and the relationship is slightly above 1". The most usual way to compare two word-vectors is cosine-similarity - which can't give any value above `1.0`. And if you're instead comparing some kind of distance, things that are more alike have *smaller* distances.

Comment: I believe that with a good set of word-vectors that covers the relevant tokens, the WMD approach will largely work: more-related sentences will show a smaller distance than less-related . If you think it's not working, you could show the results you've received, and explain why they're wrong according to your expectations, or answer the other questions I've asked for clarification about your results & expectations. But without those answers, it's hard to help!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion gojomo. May I ask you to give me an example on what you mean when you say "good set of word-vectors that covers the relevant tokens". Currently I am getting tokens from the sentences above (after removing stopwords and, as you suggested, also punctuation). How should I get smaller distance from there? I am sorry but I think I am missing some point. You could also answer this question with this example if you like. I think it will be useful for me and it will give me a good opportunity to learn something new

Comment: First, some of your words might not even be in the (2013 news-article-based) `GoogleNews` vector set. Is '5g' there? Your token 'dangerous!' (with exclamation point) is unlikely in there. So, (1) have you checked if all the words you care about are there?

Comment: Next, you've still not shown the exact output of your code. But (2) why are the distance values "`3.4, 3.92 and 3.93 (approximately)`" insufficient for your purposes?  Why do you need a "smaller" distance, and if so, which pair of sentences should have smaller distance? (Simply making all the distances smaller would have no value – distances are only meaningful in their comparison. But if you simply aesthetically like smaller numbers, you could divide all the values by 10.)